# How to share an URL Scheme link to social app

Tags: ios

I want to share an URL scheme link to social app so that when the user open social page on safari, when they click on the link, the URL scheme will call to the app I set. But when I share, it only share the text. How to share the link instead of the text.

[image]

Here is the code:

```
@IBAction func shareButtonAction(sender: AnyObject) {
        print("share")
        let myShare = "TestSafari://"
        let shareVC: UIActivityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [myShare], applicationActivities: nil)
        self.presentViewController(shareVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to put a text first then the url, in that particular order. Try this:

```
let string: String = ...
let URL: NSURL = ...
let shareVC = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [string, URL])
```

Comment: already, but It doesn't show. let myShare = "TestSafari://" let URL: NSURL = NSURL(string: "TestSafari://")! let shareVC: UIActivityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [myShare, URL], applicationActivities: nil) self.presentViewController(shareVC, animated: true, completion: nil)

Comment: what do you mean it doesn't show? what happens when you run with this code?

Comment: Here is the URL scheme: NSURL(string:"TestSafari://")

Answer (score 0):

```
let activityViewController = UIActivityViewController(
            activityItems: [image],
            applicationActivities: nil)
        activityViewController.excludedActivityTypes = [UIActivityTypeMessage,UIActivityTypeMail,UIActivityTypeCopyToPasteboard,UIActivityTypeAirDrop];
        presentViewController(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

use this code for Present ActivityViewController only change activityItems to your string.

Comment: I just want to share an URL Scheme, not an image.

Comment: activityItems: ["Put your url here"],
            applicationActivities: nil)

Comment: already, but It doesn't show. let myShare = "TestSafari://"
        let URL: NSURL = NSURL(string: "TestSafari://")!
        let shareVC: UIActivityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [myShare, URL], applicationActivities: nil)
        self.presentViewController(shareVC, animated: true, completion: nil)

Comment: LSApplicationQueriesSchemes  add this schema in your plist

Comment: I don't see any LSApplicationQueriesSchemes

Comment: I know how to add the scheme url, but when I share, it doesn't show. Can we go on chat

Comment: let URL: NSURL = NSURL(string: "<html><body><b>This is a bold string</b><br\\>Check out this amazing site: <a href='http://apple.com'>Apple</a></body></html>")!

Comment: replace your url in this url